# celery beat SpawnPoolWorker

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I have a function that Celery Beat calls it every 5 seconds and it appends something to a global variable.
I expect that every 5 seconds my function adds the element to the global variable but it does it every 20 seconds.

Here is tasks.py:

```
# tasks.py
from celery import shared_task
from .celeryapp import app
from . import cfg

@shared_task
def update_a_global_list():
    try:
        if cfg.flag:
            cfg.init()
        l = ['first']
        cfg.my_global_var.append(l)
        print("my_global_var: " + str(cfg.my_global_var))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The global variable is in a file called cfg.py:

```
# cfg.py
global my_global_var
global flag
flag = True


def init():
    global flag
    flag = False
    global my_global_var
    my_global_var = []
    print('Initialize Step')
```

The celery configuration of the project is in celeryapp.py:

```
# celeryapp.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

import os

os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')

app = Celery('tasks',
             broker='amqp://shahab_user:pass1234@localhost:5672/shahab_vhost',
             backend='rpc://')

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'every-5-seconds': {
        'task': 'send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list',
        'schedule': 5,
    },
}
```

When I run the command:

> celery -A tasks worker -l INFO

in one terminal and run the command:

> celery -A send_requests.celeryapp beat -l INFO

in another terminal, I see these logs in the worker terminal:

```
[2020-10-07 16:39:48,545: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[c24168e6-49df-4188-be2e-8ea05a563f2a]
[2020-10-07 16:39:48,545: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Initialize Step                    <===
[2020-10-07 16:39:48,561: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-1] my_global_var: [['first']]         <===
[2020-10-07 16:39:48,670: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[c24168e6-49df-4188-be2e-8ea05a563f2a] succeeded in 0.125s :None
[2020-10-07 16:39:53,440: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[ce0ec733-be6d-4640-950f-a2f47ecf1693]
[2020-10-07 16:39:53,440: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-2] Initialize Step                    <===
[2020-10-07 16:39:53,440: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-2] my_global_var: [['first']]         <===
[2020-10-07 16:39:53,547: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[ce0ec733-be6d-4640-950f-a2f47ecf1693] succeeded in 0.0940000000409782s: None
[2020-10-07 16:39:58,450: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[fae64a0a-8132-4d88-bcd1-cc59d7e73794]
[2020-10-07 16:39:58,453: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-3] Initialize Step                    <===
[2020-10-07 16:39:58,454: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-3] my_global_var: [['first']]         <===
[2020-10-07 16:39:58,532: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[fae64a0a-8132-4d88-bcd1-cc59d7e73794] succeeded in 0.0779999999795109s: None
[2020-10-07 16:40:03,453: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[86d92236-aaf4-4c62-81d6-2679eed287b2]
[2020-10-07 16:40:03,453: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-4] Initialize Step                    <===
[2020-10-07 16:40:03,453: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-4] my_global_var: [['first']]         <===
[2020-10-07 16:40:03,533: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[86d92236-aaf4-4c62-81d6-2679eed287b2] succeeded in 0.0779999999795109s: None
[2020-10-07 16:40:08,467: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[1c9fb4e4-a364-4079-98fa-f6deeb3ad638]
[2020-10-07 16:40:08,469: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-1] my_global_var: [['first'], ['first']]         <===
[2020-10-07 16:40:08,472: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[1c9fb4e4-a364-4079-98fa-f6deeb3ad638] succeeded in 0.015999999945051968s: None
[2020-10-07 16:40:13,463: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[654d9da4-2c13-46c3-88fe-7b4e73edc8d0]
[2020-10-07 16:40:13,465: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-2] my_global_var: [['first'], ['first']]         <===
[2020-10-07 16:40:13,468: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[654d9da4-2c13-46c3-88fe-7b4e73edc8d0] succeeded in 0.0s:None
[2020-10-07 16:40:18,465: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[8d777ade-870b-4133-9f26-8467e4ca4ba7]
[2020-10-07 16:40:18,467: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-3] my_global_var: [['first'], ['first']]         <===
[2020-10-07 16:40:18,470: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[8d777ade-870b-4133-9f26-8467e4ca4ba7] succeeded in 0.0s:None
[2020-10-07 16:40:23,470: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[dc8bfa49-0f3e-48bc-9c4d-33705048ffce]
[2020-10-07 16:40:23,473: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-4] my_global_var: [['first'], ['first']]         <===
[2020-10-07 16:40:23,476: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[dc8bfa49-0f3e-48bc-9c4d-33705048ffce] succeeded in 0.0s:None
[2020-10-07 16:40:28,465: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[bad53432-03cb-4843-b71b-105c8d83c971]
[2020-10-07 16:40:28,467: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-1] my_global_var: [['first'], ['first'], ['first']]     <===
[2020-10-07 16:40:28,470: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_a_global_list[bad53432-03cb-4843-b71b-105c8d83c971] succeeded in 0.0s:None
```

Why "Initialize Step" runs more that one time?

Why I have different `SpawnPoolWorker`s and they don't show me what I expected?

Thanks for your help.

[EDIT]:
According to @DejanLekic answer, I also used Django cache. But I got the same results.

This time I wrote my program in this way:

```
@shared_task
def update_global_list():
    try:
        test = []
        l = ['first']
        cached_object = cache.get('my_global_var')
        if cached_object is None:
            cache.set('my_global_var', test)
            cached_object = cache.get('my_global_var')
        cached_object.append(l)
        cache.set('my_global_var', cached_object)
        print("my_global_var : " + str(cache.get('my_global_var')))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

And I got these results:

```
[2020-10-09 14:11:45,903: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[93264e6e-3cd0-4068-ac9e-98f366cdfd51]
[2020-10-09 14:11:45,907: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-1] my_global_var : 
[['first']]
[2020-10-09 14:11:45,963: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[93264e6e-3cd0-4068-ac9e-98f366cdfd51] 
succeeded in 0.0470000000204891s: None
[2020-10-09 14:11:50,835: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[0673a0a8-8b79-4325-a9aa-015061f76166]
[2020-10-09 14:11:50,838: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-2] my_global_var : 
[['first']]
[2020-10-09 14:11:50,887: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[0673a0a8-8b79-4325-a9aa-015061f76166] 
succeeded in 0.0470000000204891s: None
[2020-10-09 14:11:55,830: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[2c58b9b3-ae37-4b8a-b28f-8e4dce2952aa]
[2020-10-09 14:11:55,834: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-3] my_global_var : 
[['first']]
[2020-10-09 14:11:55,884: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[2c58b9b3-ae37-4b8a-b28f-8e4dce2952aa] 
succeeded in 0.0470000000204891s: None
[2020-10-09 14:12:00,829: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[2fc7a1a9-27e7-41dc-936d-a017d2a283bc]
[2020-10-09 14:12:00,833: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-4] my_global_var : 
[['first']]
[2020-10-09 14:12:00,951: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[2fc7a1a9-27e7-41dc-936d-a017d2a283bc] 
succeeded in 0.125s:None
[2020-10-09 14:12:05,838: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[d382a795-8041-4331-a9ca-d4d74b2c8982]
[2020-10-09 14:12:05,840: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-1] my_global_var : 
[['first'], ['first']]
[2020-10-09 14:12:05,842: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task 
send_requests.tasks.update_global_list[d382a795-8041-4331-a9ca-d4d74b2c8982] 
succeeded in 0.015999999945051968s: None
```

Looks like different worker processes are not in sync with each other. I'm totally confused. How can I sync them?

Comment: Seems `SpawnPoolWorker`s work in parallel. how can I do my work in series?

Comment: @DejanLekic you're right. But I need a global variable to hold some data and use it in different functions. I could use database, but it hits database many times and is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using global vars in a distributed environment is just inviting trouble... It *may* work if you use a single Celery worker and threads as concurrency type. - Typical solution for this is to use caching server (Redis, memcached or similar).

*Why?* - All the worker processes will have own version of the `my_global_var` so when task that adds something to it runs, it will modify my_global_var inside *that* worker process...

Comment: Looks like different worker processes are not in sync with each other. How can I sync them?

Comment: The answer is simple - you do not. Instead "global" states that you need to share with all workers in your Celery cluster should be in a caching server like Redis or Memcached, as I already mentioned.

Comment: In fact. I'm working on a Django project that has a list of objects. These objects have an attribute called `status`. The 'status' dynamically changes and I track the changes by celery beat. I could use query to the database to say that if the status changed, save it to database. But it hits the database so many time. According to your advice it is better to use caching. But ,am I in the wrong way of implementing this?

Comment: I edited my question. I also use Django caching. Is there any difference between Django caching and Redis or Memcached?